# Get input and output size for each layer in deeplearning4java

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, deeplearning4j, dl4j

How to fetch the layer input and output size in dl4j ?

For example, something like this :

```
MultiLayerNetwork network = model.init()

for(Layer layer : network.getLayers()) {
 int[] outputShape = layer.shape() 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit more involved than that because DL4J supports layers which are more complex than simple dense or fully connected layers.

If you want to have that information to print it out, it is probably easier to use

```
String summary = model.summary();
```

If you want to do something with that information, you can take a look at the implementation of the summary method itself.

https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nn/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/nn/multilayer/MultiLayerNetwork.java#L3636-L3757

In particular linkes 3679 to 3699 as they are all about getting the input and output sizes of layers.